# Inserting table data to sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a modal that will let user choose an equipment then input the quantity.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="button-1 btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width: 26%; margin:0; height: 40px; font-size: 100%;">Choose Equipment</button>

    <!-- MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- MODAL CONTENT-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <p>Choose An Equipment Below</p>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Available Equipments</p>
            <div class="form-inline">
              <!-- DROPDOWN LIST FROM DATABASE -->
              <select id="equipment" name="equipment" class="form-control">
                <option selected="" disabled="">Select Equipment</option>
                <?php
                                $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT resource_name From resources WHERE resource_type = 'EQUIPMENT';");
                                $row = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                                echo "<option name = 'equipment' value ='". $row['resource_name'] ."'>" .$row['resource_name'] ."</option>" ;
                                }
                                ?>
              </select>
              <br><br>
              <input type="text" id="qnty-1" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity" style="width:24%; margin-left: 50px;"><br/>

              <br/><br/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <input class="submit-3" id="addToTable" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit-2" onclick="passValue1(); trigData()" data-dismiss="modal" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When submitted, the modal will disappear and the data that has been selected will display on the table. I can insert the first selected data to the database but if I choose 2 different data or same data, It will just insert one on the database. Is there a way I can insert all selected data to the database?

```
<div class="b-form-outline">
<h1>Equipment Borrowing Form</h1>
<div class="borrow-list-area">
  <table class="container-2" id="container-2">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <style>
          th,
          td {
            text-align: center;
          }
        </style>
        <th>Equipment</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th hidden>Serial No.</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script>
function passValue1() {
document.getElementById("quantity").innerHTML = 
document.getElementById("qnty-1").value;
}

$('#addToTable').click(function() {
  var eqpmnt = $('#equipment').val(),
  qnt = $('#qnty-1').val();      
  $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + eqpmnt + '</td><td>' + qnt + '</td> 
</tr>');
});
```

I've tried this insert code but again, it will only insert one row of data from the table. If anyone can please help me. Thanks a lot!

```
<?php

include('dbconnector.php');


$id_num = $_POST['idnumber'];
$s_date = $_POST['startdate'];
$e_date = $_POST['enddate'];
$s_time = $_POST['starttime'];
$e_time = $_POST['endtime'];
$prpse = $_POST['purpose'];
$equipment = $_POST['equipment'];
$qnty = $_POST['quantity'];
$subj = $_POST['subject'];
$onCamp = isset($_POST['check-1']) ? $_POST['check-1'] : "Off-Campus";

// CREATES A NEW TRANSACTION THAT WAS SUBMITTED USING THE BORROW FOWM

$query = "SELECT * FROM resources;";                // ACCESS TABLE RESOURCES
$con = mysqli_query($conn, $query);                 
if ($con->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
        $rsname = $row['resource_name'];
        if (strcmp($equipment, $rsname) == 0) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (id_number, start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time, purpose, quantity, subject, use_place) VALUES ('$id_num', '$s_date', '$e_date', '$s_time', '$e_time', '$prpse', '$qnty', '$subj', '$onCamp');";

        }
    }
}

if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    $message = "Error Sending Form";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
else {       
    header("refresh: 1; url=borrow.php");   
}

?>
```

Adjusted for @Jon Stirling

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM resources;";                // ACCESS TABLE RESOURCES
$con = mysqli_query($conn, $query);                 
if ($con->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($con)){
        $rsname = $row['resource_name'];
        if (strcmp($equipment, $rsname) == 0) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (id_number, start_date, end_date, start_time, end_time, purpose, quantity, subject, use_place) VALUES ('$id_num', '$s_date', '$e_date', '$s_time', '$e_time', '$prpse', '$qnty', '$subj', '$onCamp');";

            if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {

                $message = "Error Sending Form";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
            }
            else {       
                header("refresh: 1; url=borrow.php");   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will only insert one because you keep overriding your `$sql` variable inside the loop, but only executing it once the loop is done. Try moving the `mysqli_query` into the loop.

Comment: @JonStirling Uhm I tried to put it inside the the loop sir but still does not record the second row of data to the database. Only inserts the first one.

Comment: Show us that code then.

Comment: Tried to move it inside the first, second, and third loop but does not work sir @JonStirling :(

Comment: Use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

Comment: @JonStirling Posted the code above sir.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: Why `mysqli_multi_query`?

Comment: @JonStirling My bad sir. changed that one now. that was the old one. Sorry.

Comment: "does not work" means what exactly? What is the end result? You get the JS output Or you get the refresh? Or something else? Did the query succeed? If not, what was the error (P.S. to enable error reporting if you haven't already: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.)

Comment: `header("refresh: 1; url=borrow.php");` Get rid of this, or move it to after the while.

Comment: Another side suggestion, use descriptive variable names. `$con` for a MySQL result is con-fusing.

Comment: Also, your check `strcmp($equipment, $rsname) == 0`. You only do an insert if those variables are the same strings, given your table naming, I would only expect there to be one row with each name, so only one iteration of the loop would match anyway?

Comment: @JonStirling With strcmp($equipment, $rsname) == 0 as i have checked, its a useless line. I was aiming to compare the $equipment to the data on the table resources but its basically useless because on the modal, the option that will show will only be the equipments on the database. So I've removed that one already